# Simplest way to get data from Google Analytics?

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am building a service like Wix.com, users can build simple mutli-pages website with ease. Every website will be including in a global Google Analytics account with a unique profile, then the tracking code is to be placed in the website pages.

Now, on the website dashboard i want to show the online visitors and the total number of visists for the website for each website separatly, trying to do so i have :

Tried using GAPI (http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/) but due to Google Analytics major update it doesn't work anymore.

I found Google Core reporting API for Analytics, but i believe it's made for 3rd party applications that accesses GA data for their clients, meaning that the user should have a Google account and GA profile for the website, and the App just connects to the account and retrieves data. And this of course isn't the case here; i can't ask the user to create a Google account and embed the tracking code in the website HTML; else what am i here for ?

Got the picture ? I need the simplest method to do this, no fancy stuff.

PS: Minutes ago i found this: Google Analytics Query Explorer (http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/), it's a 3rd party app that builds custom queries for GA and gives you the link, something like that :

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids= (the ID) &dimensions=ga%3AvisitCount&metrics=ga%3Avisitors&segment=gaid%3A%3A-1&start-date=2013-02-01&end-date=2013-02-23&max-results=50

Now, trying to access the URL (thinking; this is easy :) ) the respond is a request for login first :

{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have fewer than 50 clients this plan is not going to work the way you're asking for. (There is a limit of 50 profiles per account.)

1. The client will have to make their own GA number and provide it to you as a setting for their website.
2. In order to display the customers reports on a dashboard on your site you're also going to have to get them to authorize a GA App you create for access.